# PHP and Accessing ComplexType in SOAP Web Service

Tags: php, web-services, soap, complextype

I want to make a call to a webservice. And the webservice is contain some complextype elements. I'm getting good results with ASP.NET and soapUI. But I'm getting an error with PHP. I couldn't figured out.

So, could you help me please?

Thanks.

The function I want to call:

```
<xs:element name="GetHotelSearch">
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="searchClass" nillable="true" type="q13:HotelSearch" xmlns:q13="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Model"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="recorCount" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sortType" type="q14:SortType" xmlns:q14="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Model"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="sortFields" nillable="true" type="q15:ArrayOfSortField" xmlns:q15="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Model"/>
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="GetHotelSearchResponse">
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="GetHotelSearchResult" nillable="true" type="q16:ArrayOfHotelSummary" xmlns:q16="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Model"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="recorCount" type="xs:int"/>
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

ComplexTypes:

```
   <xs:complexType name="HotelSearch">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="BRANCHID" type="xs:int"/>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UNIQUECODE" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>

   <xs:simpleType name="SortType">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:enumeration value="Ascending">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">1</EnumerationValue>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
         <xs:enumeration value="Descending">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">2</EnumerationValue>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>

   <xs:element name="SortType" nillable="true" type="tns:SortType"/>
   <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfSortField">
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SortField" type="tns:SortField"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>

   <xs:element name="ArrayOfSortField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfSortField"/>
   <xs:simpleType name="SortField">
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:enumeration value="PENSIONTYPENAME">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">1</EnumerationValue>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
         <xs:enumeration value="HOTELNAME">
            <xs:annotation>
               <xs:appinfo>
                  <EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">2</EnumerationValue>
               </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
         </xs:enumeration>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
   <xs:element name="SortField" nillable="true" type="tns:SortField"/>
```

.NET Code (it's working):

```
int _recordCount = 10;
List<HotelSummary> hotels = hc.GetHotelSearch(new HotelSearch()
{
    BRANCHID = 000,
    UNIQUECODE = "YIO"
}, ref _recordCount, SortType.Ascending, new SortField[] { SortField.HOTELNAME }).ToList();
```

The XML (it's working with soapUI):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:mod="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Model">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetHotelSearch>
         <tem:searchClass>
             <mod:BRANCHID>000</mod:BRANCHID>
             <mod:UNIQUECODE>YIO</mod:UNIQUECODE>
         </tem:searchClass>
         <tem:recorCount>10</tem:recorCount>
         <tem:sortType>Ascending</tem:sortType>
         <tem:sortFields>
             <mod:SortField>HOTELNAME</mod:SortField>
         </tem:sortFields>
      </tem:GetHotelSearch>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And PHP Code (It's not WORKING):

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

$url='http://localhost/Service/Service.svc?wsdl';

$client = new SoapClient($url);

$HotelSearch= array('BRANCHID' => 000,'UNIQUECODE' => 'YIO');
$SortField= array('SortField' => 'HOTELNAME');

$result = $client->GetHotelSearch($HotelSearch, 10, 'Ascending', $SortField);

$array = $result->GetHotelSearchResult->HotelSummary;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 155. in D:\[.Projeler]\musteri\webservis\test.php:98 Stack trace: #0 D:\[.Projeler]\musteri\webservis\test.php(98): SoapClient->__call('GetHotelSearch', Array) #1 D:\[.Projeler]\musteri\webservis\test.php(98): SoapClient->GetHotelSearch(Array, 10, 'Ascending', Object(stdClass)) #2 {main} thrown in D:\[.Projeler]\musteri\webservis\test.php on line 98
```

With try and catch:

```
End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 155.
```

Comment: Can you get a getLastRequest and paste what you get here? I just want to see the actual xml sent.

Comment: @AbhishekAsthana; http://pastebin.com/NUGcs8wF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I tried to recreate your problem and as i didn't have access to your service i choose [Temperature Conversion](http://webservices.daehosting.com/services/TemperatureConversions.wso?WSDL) which did not work till i added

```
$SoapCallParameters = new stdClass();
$SoapCallParameters->nCelcius = 30;
$obj = $client->CelciusToFahrenheit($SoapCallParameters);
```

maybe you could also try using the stdClass something like

```
$hotelSearch = new stdClass();
$hotelSearch->searchClass->BRANCHID = 000;
$hotelSearch->searchClass->UNIQUECODE = YIO;
```

**DISCLAIMER**: You should know that i am learning php and the only way i learn is by solving problems, so this is me trying to solve a problem.

my working temperature conversion working code is below:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$url = "http://webservices.daehosting.com/services/TemperatureConversions.wso?WSDL";

$client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0)); 

var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

$SOAPCall = "CelciusToFahrenheit";
$SoapCallParameters = new stdClass();
$SoapCallParameters->nCelcius = 30;
$obj = $client->CelciusToFahrenheit($SoapCallParameters);
var_dump($obj);
```

I had help from @Sergiu Paraschiv

[internal server error when running soapclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794982/internal-server-error-when-running-soapclient/18795161?noredirect=1#comment27716394_18795161)

Comment: thanks for your help! That's worked. I tried to use the **stdClass** like you did, and it's worked. Thanks again.