# internal server error when running soapclient

Tags: php, soap-client

This should be an easy one for the pros here. I am using the soapClient php library to make a simple call(see code below).

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
        $url = "http://webservices.daehosting.com/services/TemperatureConversions.wso?WSDL";

        $client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0)); 

        var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

        $SOAPCall = "CelciusToFahrenheit";
        $SoapCallParameters = "30";
        $obj = $client->CelciusToFahrenheit($SoapCallParameters);
        var_dump($obj);

        var_dump($client->getLastRequest());
    ?>

</body>
```

When i execute i get the below error. I have looked in the Apache error logs and I see the same error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Internal Server Error in C:\wamp\www\phpSandbox\index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://webservi...', '', 1, 0) #1 C:\wamp\www\phpSandbox\index.php(16): SoapClient->__call('CelciusToFahren...', Array) #2 C:\wamp\www\phpSandbox\index.php(16): SoapClient->CelciusToFahrenheit('30') #3 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\phpSandbox\index.php on line 16
```

I have also done some reading from people facing similar problems but not able to find a solution.

I know for sure that the soapClient library is activated because the following code work

```
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'CelciusToFahrenheitResponse CelciusToFahrenheit(CelciusToFahrenheit $parameters)' (length=80)
  1 => string 'FahrenheitToCelciusResponse FahrenheitToCelcius(FahrenheitToCelcius $parameters)' (length=80)
  2 => string 'WindChillInCelciusResponse WindChillInCelcius(WindChillInCelcius $parameters)' (length=77)
  3 => string 'WindChillInFahrenheitResponse WindChillInFahrenheit(WindChillInFahrenheit $parameters)' (length=86)
```

any help to resolve this error and possible explanation for the error will be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Internal Server Error` usually means the server got your request but it did not like one of the parameters.

Lookin at your WSDL I can see `CelciusToFahrenheit` expects one parameter with this definition:

```
<xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="nCelcius" type="xs:decimal"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

A complex type is an object. So try this:

```
$SoapCallParameters = new stdClass();
$SoapCallParameters->nCelcius = 30;
$obj = $client->CelciusToFahrenheit($SoapCallParameters);
```

Comment: Tried that and now got another error Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'nCelcius' property in C:\wamp\www\phpSandbox\index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\phpSandbox\index.php(16): SoapClient->__call('CelciusToFahren...', Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\phpSandbox\index.php(16): SoapClient->CelciusToFahrenheit(Object(stdClass)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\phpSandbox\index.php on line 16

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about the stdClass.

Comment: I used to think that Internal Server Error meant that server was busy and could not handle my request.

Comment: Well, it really depends on the server implementation. You can expect about anything, don't rely on response messages unless they are documented. That's why I used the word _usually_ :)

Comment: cool. I was actually trying to solve [another problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762963/php-and-accessing-complextype-in-soap-web-service?noredirect=1#comment27691304_18762963) when i got this error. Also, is " A sequence is an array" statement true? If yes could you add it back to your answer so that i know it when i come back to refresh my memory. TY

Comment: Actually, no. That's why I removed it. A sequence is a structure telling those _reading_ (you, a server, etc.) the WSDL that the order of elements inside it is important.